# Unable to read XML file

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I am new to UWP and can't get my XAML page to read an XML file.  I want to take the entries in the XML file and load them into a dropdown.  I have not set the dropdown up in my XAML page yet, but am just trying to read in an XML file.  When I get to the C# method (Page_Loaded) it gets an error saying I can't do a .Load command in the UI thread and it needs to be moved to Task.Run.  Here is my XAML...

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestProject.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestProject"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Page_Loaded">
</Page>
```

Here is my code behind...

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace TestProject
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            XDocument file = XDocument.Load(@"C:\AvailableTestsXMLFile.txt");             

        }       
    }
}
```

// Any help would be appreciated!

// here is the exact error...Synchronous operations should not be performed on the UI thread.  Consider wrapping this method in Task.Run.

Comment: “It gets an error saying...” Don't paraphrase error messages, copy the error message into your question.

Comment: Cancel this as I need to do this project in WPF.

Comment: @ScottS Do you mean you want to implement this function in wpf but not UWP?

Answer (score 2):

1. you could check this site: [UWP XmlDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument)
2. In UWP you can't access files accept from your application folder without filepicker. In a future Update you'll get some more possibilities, but for now - no
3. Try to make a method:

   ```
   public async Task LoadXML(string file)
   {
      await Task.Run(() => { XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(file); });
   }
   ```